# How to create a categorical column from a single column using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, spotfire

I have table with a single column & I want to create a logic from below metrics using SQL

Table:

```
Site Number | Categorical Column
43  
50  
62  
88  
93
```

My Metrics:

- for site number = 43 & 93 then A
- for Site number = 50 & 93 then B
- for Site number = 62 & 93 then C
- for Site number = 50 & 88 then D

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your logic!!

Comment: is it plsql or sql-server? What does this have to do with CTE and Spotfire?

Comment: I am trying to create the new categorical / calculated column in Spotfire using Case Statements but I am not able to accomplish the B & D. I have also tried creating the case statement in PL-SQL developer but no luck.

Comment: Can you explain your logic a little deeper? Then I should be able to help you with the Spotfire expression

Comment: Vidya, right now it seems like you've asked an extremely basic question and have made no effort to solve the issue yourself. please share what you've tried and why, specifically, it doesn't work. you may have to RTFM..

Answer (score 2):

Your question is quite unclear. Are you just looking for this?

```
select
  case when [Site Number] in (43,93) then 'A' else '' end + 
  case when [Site Number] in (50,93) then 'B' else '' end + 
  case when [Site Number] in (62,93) then 'C' else '' end + 
  case when [Site Number] in (50,88) then 'D' else '' end
```

If this is not what you want, edit your question to actually contain a proper example.